# Reference to root element as key in JSON Path Expression

Tags: jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I have a JSON like this

```
{ 
    "a" : 1,
    "key_to_find" : "value_of_key",
    "nested" : {
         "value_of_key" : "real_value",
         "b" : 2
    }
}
```

I want to create a JSON Path expression to get "real_value", but I don't now the key "value_of_key" so I need to dynamically reference it.
I tried something like:

$.nested['$.key_to_find']

but it doesn't work.
How can I reference to root element value as key to get children values? Is that possible?

I need to use it inside AWS Step Functions, so no programming languages/libraries can be used.

Answer (score 2):

References like this aren't part of JSON Path, though I think since you're using them inside AWS, you'll need to see exactly what they support.  It varies.  Widely.

We (the team working on the [coming specification](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base)) have looked at the idea of a `key()` or `index()` function, however.  You may find [this discussion](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base/issues/156) enlightening as well.

Comment: Thank you, I am following the discussion in the link so correct me if I am wrong. Actually there is no solution for this, but you are already working on a possible functions implementation to address this kind of use cases?

Comment: There are some proposals, yes, but nothing has been added to the spec, yet, for this specific use case.